# HC-SR04 sensor acting crazy

Tags: arduino, distance, sensors

I'm quite new to Arduino but I'm trying to learn but currently, I'm having an issue. The output when the sensor stationary shows distance spikes. Is it a faulty sensor or is there a problem in the code?

Output:

```
Distance: 3540.65
Distance: 25.93
Distance: 3528.96
Distance: 25.42
Distance: 3550.34
Distance: 25.88
Distance: 3536.78
Distance: 36.27
Distance: 3501.94
Distance: 25.42
Distance: 28.37
Distance: 3531.37
Distance: 24.51
Distance: 26.99
```

Code:

```
  * HC-SR04 example sketch
  *
  * https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/Isaac100/getting-started-with-the- hc-sr04-ultrasonic-sensor-036380
  *
  * by Isaac100
  */

const int trigPin = 9;
const int echoPin = 10;

float duration, distance;

void setup() {
 pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
 digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
 delayMicroseconds(2);
 digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
 delayMicroseconds(10);
 digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

 duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
 distance = (duration*.0343)/2;
 Serial.print("Distance: ");
 Serial.println(distance);
 delay(100);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer this with the lack of information provided, and this doesn't appear to be a programming question. How far was something from the sensor at the time of the readings? What is the max distance it's rated for? Was the lens dirty? How is it being read?

Comment: It was working before

Comment: it was like 30 cm away. I'm not sure about the max distance but before it was managing to see up to 3 meters i think. It is clean...

Comment: Try two things: Increase the delay at the end of your loop and also test away from clutter (measure to wall). Does this improve your performance?

Comment: I think it works but oddly it still shows nonsense whenever I'm bringing it close to laptops LCD. Perhaps the EMF interacts with sensors electronics or even with Arduino. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that you found answer to your question, but in future I would recommend you to filter those values. Maybe think about simple median filter or low pass filter.
Median filter:
Take last X(may be 5 for example) values and put them into an array.
Sort the array. Get the array[(X/2)] value. Now its a bit more usefull. 
You may dynamically add data so you dont have to accumulate 10 of them and then filter it. For example if you receive new measurement A:
A - new measurement value
X - amount of data to accumulate (filter strength)
0 <= i < X 
array[X] - array with accumulated data

array[i] = A;
i++;
if(i==X) i=0;

Simple as that.